# How can I quickly iterate over bits in a binary file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, bit, bin

I would like to quickly iterate over bits in a binary file using python3. I need to read all bytes and convert all bytes to bits and apply a shift register for each bit. As soon as the shift register takes a certain value that is similar to the value of the sync marker and has a difference of only 3 bits or less (Levenshtein.hamming), what is done is a function. I made a code like this, but it's slow. How can I speed it up?

```
import Levenshtein, argparse, io
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", help="Output binary file name")
parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", help="Input binary file name")
inputfile=parser.parse_args().input
outfile=parser.parse_args().output

def get_byte(f):
    while(byte := f.read(1)):
        return bin(int().from_bytes(byte, 'big'))[2:].zfill(8)

def func():
    # text
    return

def main(input_file, sync_marker, sync_buffer, out, out_filename):
    bit_array=''
    k=0
    while True:
        if(len(bit_array)<=1):
            bits_array=get_byte(f=input_file)
            k=0
        if(bits_array!=None):
            bit_array=bits_array[k:]
            k+=1
            sync_buffer=sync_buffer[1:]+bit_array[:1]
            err=int(Levenshtein.hamming(sync_buffer, str(sync_marker)))
            if(err<int(3)):
                func()
        if(bits_array==None):
            with open(out_filename, 'wb') as out_bytes_file:
                out_bytes_file.write(out.getvalue())
            input_file.close()
            break
    return

if(__name__=='__main__'):
    f=open(inputfile, "rb")
    out_file=io.BytesIO()
    sync_marker='0100101001'
    sync_buffer=str('0'*int(len(sync_marker)))
    main(input_file=f, sync_buffer=sync_buffer, sync_marker=sync_marker, out=out_file, out_filename=outfile)
```

Comment: Bytes are composed of bits, so it is confusing when you say "convert all bytes to bits" it's done, bytes are bits. Also,  `f.read(1)`, that is going to be real slow. Just read all of the file into a byte object then grab individual bytes out of it. Although looping in python is notoriously slow you might consider a library like numpy.

Comment: I mean that I need to convert each byte into a sequence of "1" and "0". I can't read the entire file as I'm working with files over 10 GB and don't want to pack it all into RAM.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can replace your bin()/ zfill with just returning the byte. Then your math your doing, you can use a mask. That way you'll never convert to a "binary array" which is actually string.

Comment: bits_array[k:] gives the lowest 8-k bits? So all you have to do is create a mask with k ones and use `bits_array & mask` that would give you the same result, but leave you answer as an integer.

Comment: Hm. Yes, I think I should try this.

Comment: If your file is too big, then you need to have a buffering strategy, I have a 133MB file if I read all of the bytes and then iterate over them it takes ~2 seconds. If I call f.read1) for each byte it takes 7 seconds.

Comment: Could you demonstrate your code?

Comment: It isn't doing anything, it is literally opening a file and iterating over the bytes. I just tried it out to see how much of a difference in performance it makes. `bbs = open(filename, 'rb').read()` then `for b in bbs: pass`. vs the `while( b := f.read(1) )`